# trim function not working for string array

Tags: php

This is a really odd behavior that I can't explain. I have a CSV file that I'm trying to format. The lines could have trailing ','s that I want to remove.

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csv);
$csv = '';
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $csv .= trim($line, ',') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

The trim is not doing anything and just returning the line back as it is. Just to make sure I copied a line from the csv `trim("a,b,c,d,,", ',');` which works fine. Can anyone tell me why the above code won't work?

Comment: shouldn't your `trim($t, ',')` be `trim($line, ',')`?

Comment: sorry that was a typo on my end. I'm doing trim($line

Comment: Make sure `,` is really the last character. Maybe there are spaces or carriage return.

Comment: Why do you want to trim off the trailing commas?  They are valid for a CSV file, when there is no data in that column.  Are you having trouble loading this CSV file elsewhere?

Comment: You might need to double-check the data. Try `$new_line = trim($line, ','); if($new_line == $line) var_dump($line);` and make su the string and *character count* are what you expect.

Comment: Don't manually edit the CSV file.  Parse it into an array, then edit the array.  Then you can write the modified array back to a CSV file.  Are you trying to strip off the last two values?  Or just the last _blank_ value(s)?

Comment: I see the issue now. the line did have blank spaces at the end. thanks for the tip @aynber

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the CSV file was created on a different operating system, it may use different line breaks than `PHP_EOL`. So trim any line break characters in addition to commas.

```
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $csv .= trim($line, ",\r\n") . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't manually edit the CSV file.  Parse it into an array, then edit the array.  Then you can write the modified array back to a CSV file.

You can use [`fputcsv`](https://php.net/fputcsv) to write the data to a file, or [`str_putcsv`](https://gist.github.com/johanmeiring/2894568) (a custom function).

```
$newData = [];
$data = array_map('str_getcsv', $lines); // parse each line as a CSV

foreach ($data as $row) {
    $row = array_filter($row); // remove blank values

    // for some dumb reason, php has `str_getcsv` but not `str_putcsv`
    // so let's use `str_putcsv` from: https://gist.github.com/johanmeiring/2894568
    $newData[] = str_putcsv($row);
}

$newData = implode(PHP_EOL, $newData);
```